# Determine first day of a week by a given date in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to determine the first day of a week by a given date in Moment.js. This is my code:

```
var begin = moment("2015-08-15").startOf('week').isoWeekday(0);
console.log(begin);
var end = moment("2015-08-15").endOf('week').isoWeekday(0);
console.log(end);
```

I get the following output:

```
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-01T22:00:00.000Z }
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-09T21:59:59.999Z }
```

According to the docs the local is 'en' by default and this would mean that first day of week is Sunday. In my opinion the correct result should be:

```
begin = 2015-08-09
end = 2015-08-15
```

When I changed `isoWeekday` from '0' to '1' the result looks like this:

```
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-02T22:00:00.000Z }
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-10T21:59:59.999Z }
```

This is also wrong. The correct answer would be:

```
begin = 2015-08-10
end = 2015-08-16
```

Comment: I don't think that is a local thing but more an opinion or a religious thing to start the week on sunday.

Comment: Are you saying momentjs has this wrong? If so what are we trying to answer here?

Comment: I think you need to do `startOf('isoweek')` instead of `startOf('week')`

Comment: @putvande - [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) specifically start on Monday, which moment models correctly with `'isoWeek'`.  For the US, [the defacto usage is to start on Sunday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/), and that's what moment models for `'week'` in the `en` locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer will be:

```
var begin = moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week').format("YYYY MM DD");
var end = moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week').format("YYYY MM DD");
```

Thanks to help by @MattJohnson

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that you are getting `startOf()` your local week of 2015-08-15, which is Sunday 2015-08-09, and then your are resetting this **ISO week**, which is Monday to Sunday, to its first day, which is of course Monday 2015-08-02.

You need to use `startOf('isoWeek')` for consistent behaviour.

Comment: The date 2015-08-02 is a Sunday, not a Monday.

Comment: Hey @punund,
When i use this code:

`var begin = moment("2015-08-15").startOf('isoWeekday');
console.log(begin);
var end = moment("2015-08-15").endOf('isoWeekday');
console.log(end);`

The result is:

`var begin = 2015-08-14;
var end = 2015-08-14;`

Did i made something wrong?

Comment: `'isoWeek'`, not `'isoWeekday'`.   Also, you should use `format` or another output function rather than looking at the internal (underscored) properties.

Comment: Hey @Matt Johnson, when i use `isoWeek` as a result is get this answers for begin : `Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-09T22:00:00.000Z }` and this for end: `Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-08-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD", _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale: Object, _d: Date 2015-08-16T21:59:59.999Z }`. Did i still made something wrong?

Comment: Use `format`. Don't look at the `_i`, or `_d`, etc.  Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vpfer342/

Comment: @MattJohnson. Thanks it is now working. Can you explain to me why the date completely changes after you add the format method?

Comment: Prefixing a field with an underscore is a common JavaScript convention to indicate it's meant for private/internal use only.  In moment.js, the fields are often used in combination within the functions.  For example, had you adjusted the time zone, both `_d` and `_offset` would have have to be taken into account.  However in your particular case, only `_d` is evaluated - it's just that your particular browser (Firefox?) chooses to show dates in their UTC equivalent rather than in local time.  Since it shows 22:00Z, I guess you are in UTC+02:00.

Comment: If you ignore underscore-prefixed fields, and use only the public API, you will not have to worry about this.